# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am doing a binary search and I am getting this error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'list' and 'int'

Here is the problematic code:

```
def binary_search(arr,val):
    if len(arr)==0 or len(arr)==1 and arr[0]!=val:
        return false

    mid=arr[len(arr)//2]


    if val==mid:
        return true


    if val<mid:
            return binary_search(len(arr//2,val))
    if val>mid:
        return binary_search(len(arr//2+1,val))

arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

print(binary_search(arr,3))
```

How should this be solved?

Comment: When you make a recursive call in ``return binary_search(len(arr//2,val))``, you are trying to make it on half of the array. In python, you can't divide an array like that. Get a sub array like arr[0:len(arr)//2].

Comment: Also there are syntax errors in true and false

Answer (score 1):

With `arr//2`, you're dividing `arr`, a list, by `2`, causing the exception. You should pass to the recursive function a slice of `arr` instead:

```
def binary_search(arr,val):
    if len(arr)==0 or len(arr)==1 and arr[0]!=val:
        return False

    mid=arr[len(arr)//2]


    if val==mid:
        return True


    if val<mid:
            return binary_search(arr[:len(arr)//2],val)
    if val>mid:
        return binary_search(arr[len(arr)//2+1:],val)

arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

print(binary_search(arr,3))
```